# Import .csv file to sqlite3 database table on QT gui

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qt4

I am writing a QT GUI application that will import a .csv file to a sqlite database table
my .csv file is in the path /home/aj/import_table.csv
and my database is in /home/aj/testdatabase.db

i wrote the below code block---

```
void MainWindow::on_importButton_clicked()
{
    QSqlDatabase db=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName("/home/aj/testdatabase.db");

    QString querystr;
    querystr=QString(".separator ","");
    QSqlQuery query(querystr,db);
    if(query.exec())
    {
        qDebug()<<"SUCCESSFULLY QUEIRED ";

        QString querystr2;
        querystr=QString(".import import_table.csv test_table");
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<<"ERROR DURING QUERY "<<db.lastError().text();
    }
}
```

but it is throwing error at compile time--

> /home/aj/sqlite3test/mainwindow.cpp:34: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
>   /home/aj/sqlite3test/mainwindow.cpp:34: error: conversion from ‘const char [1]’ to ‘QChar’ is ambiguous
>   /home/aj/sqlite3test/mainwindow.cpp:34: error: conversion from ‘const char [1]’ to ‘QChar’ is ambiguous
>   /usr/local/Trolltech/Qt-4.8.4/include/QtCore/qstring.h:90: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘QString::QString(int, QChar)’ [-fpermissive]

any solutions ???

is it happening because .separator and .import are sqlite terminal command and cannot be executed via the querystr=Qstring("... ... ..."); format ???

Comment: "but it is throwing error at runtime" - those look like compilation errors to me.

Comment: Which is line 34 in that function?

Comment: sorry, compile time..

Comment: querystr=QString(".separator ","");
is line number 34

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
querystr=QString(".separator ","");
```

is trying to construct a QString using two `const char *` as arguments to the constructor. According to [the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html) there is no constructor that accepts this combination.

I think you meant to include the (") quotes inside the string. You need to escape them with backslashes, like this:

```
querystr=QString(".separator \",\"");
```

so that the compiler knows that they should be part of the string, rather than delimiting it.

That should fix your compilation error, **HOWEVER** your last comment is correct, the [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) states:

> And, of course, it is important to remember that the dot-commands are
>   interpreted by the sqlite3.exe command-line program, not by SQLite
>   itself. So none of the dot-commands will work as an argument to SQLite
>   interfaces like sqlite3_prepare() or sqlite3_exec().

In other words, if you want to read in a CSV file from a C++ program you have written yourself, you will have to parse the file in your own code and insert the records via SQL INSERT commands.

Comment: thanks a lot for confirming my doubt about the .dot-commands.

compilation error is removed now, but it still doesnt work.

any tutorial links / documentation on parsing the .dot-command to my c++ programs ???

Comment: @AmarjitBiswas As stated in the answer, you cannot call .dot commands directly from a C++ program. You could use eg. popen to run the sqlite cli tool and use it to do the importing, but I would not recommend that. I recommend writing your own simple parse and insert routine.